# Want send files along with some other values also in spring rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am having a requirement in which I need to make rest service for consuming the multiple files and some other fields also, how to create a service controller for such type of requirements, for only attachments, many answers are there but files+other data I didn't find suitable answer, my pojo class looked like

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class FileUploadDTO {

    private String name;
    private String location;
    private List<MultipartFile> file;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public List<MultipartFile> getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(List<MultipartFile> file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

I am trying to consume this from rest client, please suggest the right approach.

Comment: did it work? If yes, can you please accept the answer. Otherwise, let me know the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this-

In your controller make a POST method handler

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test/upload")
public @ResponseBody String uploadFileTest(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("stringValue") String stringValue, @RequestParam(value = "booleanValue", required = false) String booleanValue) {
    //your logic
}
```

From your client, make a form POST call with required params.
JSON input with `@RequestBody` won't work as file is not supported in json data types.

You can try with POJO as well, but for that to work skip putting `@RequestBody` in you controller input.

**EDIT:** Tested working example with POJO

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test/upload")
public @ResponseBody String uploadFileTest(Dummy dummy) {
    return dummy.getFiles().get(0).getOriginalFilename();
}
```

and POJO:

```
public class Dummy {

private List<MultipartFile> files; 
private String stringValue;
private String booleanValue;

public List<MultipartFile> getFiles() {
    return files;
}
public void setFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) {
    this.files = files;
}
public String getStringValue() {
    return stringValue;
}
public void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
    this.stringValue = stringValue;
}
public String getBooleanValue() {
    return booleanValue;
}
public void setBooleanValue(String booleanValue) {
    this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u Can do it like This : use @RequestPart for files like images and any attachments 
and use @RequsetParam to "name/value" parameters like String , Long , ...

```
@PutMapping("/upload") //or @PostMapping
public void ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestPart file , @RequesParam Long size , @RequestParam String fileName){
//ToDo Something
}
```